# application settings variable instead of textbox.text

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i want to save a variable to application settings and i dont want it to be in my invisible textbox1.text. i just want a plain old variable that i can manipulate during runtime and then have it save it after i reload the application. what do i do instead of attaching my.settings to textbox1.text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a setting in the Project Properties, and just refer to `My.Settings.<YourSettingName>` instead of using a textbox.